# if (Last 2 digits of a number are between 00 and 99)?

Tags: java, if-statement

Im writing a program where I ask for a students ID and then I run the program based of the last 2 digits of their id

So

```
if("last two digits of id are between 0 and 50") { 
Do blah blah blah
}
```

and

```
if("Last two digits of id are between 50 and 99") {
Do blah blah blah
}
```

The actual ID is going to have around 8 digits.

I'd greatly appreciate if someone told me what I should put in the quotation marks in my code up there^ (and explain what's going on if possible)

Comment: Convert integer to string, substring last 2 digits, parse to integer, check value between x and y. Easy.

Comment: You should first attempt it and then ask for help. But Glen Thomas covered it how you must do it.

Comment: Another thing to learn about and pay close attention to: inclusive and exclusive ranges.  Which group should 50 be in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int last2Digits = studentId % 100;

if (last2Digits <= 50) { // 0 to 50
    // Do something
} else { // 51 to 99
    // Do something else
}
```

Take `studentId % 100` and that should be between `0-99`.

Comment: This is *far* more preferable to the conversion chain `int` -> `String` -> `int`.

Comment: @Makato It probably isn't. The studentID is really inherently a key, i.e. a String. There's no evidence that was ever held in an `int` in the first place.

Comment: Wow thanks, I didn't realize that modulus 100 was the last two numbers, and I'm new to java so I cant convert strings to integer, so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> modulo 100 gives the last two digits

**If the Id is integer**

```
if(id%100 <= 50) //since modulo of a number cannot be less that 00
{ 
Do blah blah blah
}

if(id%100 >50 ) //since modulo of a two digit number cannot be more that 99
 {
Do blah blah blah
}
```

**If the Id is String**

```
if(Integer.parseInt(id)%100 <= 50) 
{ 
Do blah blah blah
}

if(Integer.parseInt(id)%100 >50 ) 
 {
Do blah blah blah
}
```